# GraphQL multiple queries on model

Tags: javascript, python, graphql

If I have a model Customer which used to have methods to get the customer balance (i.e. `getBalance()`), maximum Credit (i.e. `maxCredit()`), number of Orders (i.e. `noOfOrders()`), how would you implement such a scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the different access scenarios and then create the queries and mutations first.

For you case, query could be something like 

`query { customer(id: 1234) { balance maxcredit noOfOrders } }`

And now build the server accordingly.